# Mongo $text search against datetime field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**e.g., a $text search for the string "07-04-1776" does not do a good job returning matching results against a datetime field.**

I realize there are other operators like $date, $lte, $gte, but the issue is that I need to allow the user to run a search from a search box against all fields in the collection. This approach does a satisfactory job finding matches for string and numeric data, but datetime fields are essentially ignored.

Thanks!

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: Mongo query.   Front end of the app is javascript